# Import npm package into a Vue.js Single File component

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, jodit

I would like to use Jodit in a SFC, but I am not sure how this is supposed to be done. I realized there is a wrapper (`jodit-vue`), but for educational purposes, I would like to know how it's done without it. I created a Vue CLI project with default presets, and all I changed is the `App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <textarea id="editor" name="editor"></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import "../node_modules/jodit/build/jodit.min.js"

export default {
  name: 'App',
  created(){
    let editor = new Jodit('#editor');
    editor.value = '<p>start</p>';
  }
}
</script>

<style>
@import "../node_modules/jodit/build/jodit.min.css" ;
</style>
```

This produces the error: `error  'Jodit' is not defined  no-undef`, and
if I change the import to:

```js
import Jodit from "../node_modules/jodit/build/jodit.min.js"
```

Then the compilation is fine, but the browser console says:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: _node_modules_jodit_build_jodit_min_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a is not a constructor
```

Admittedly, I am new to all of this, but pointing me to the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jodit` module exports the `Jodit` constructor, so your component would import it like this:

```js
import { Jodit } from 'jodit'
```

You'd also need the [Jodit styles](https://github.com/xdan/jodit/blob/d2de5af/build/jodit.min.css), which could be imported like this:

```js
import 'jodit/build/jodit.min.css'
```

To create a `Jodit` instance, we need to provide an element or selector to an existing `<textarea>`. The Vue component's elements are available in the [`mounted()` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) (not in the `created()` hook), so that's where we would initialize:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    const editor = new Jodit('#editor')
    editor.value = '<p>start</p>'
  },
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-jodit-in-vue-758wg?file=/src/components/Jodit.vue)